# ngFor over json to generate a table

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have json array as follows,

> [   {
>       "AccountName": "test1",
>       "Amount": "-28.11"   },   {
>       "AccountName": "test2",
>       "Amount": "400"   },   {
>       "AccountName": "test3",
>       "Amount": "-500"   } ]

i need to generate a table as follows,

```
test1 | test2 | test3
---------------------
-28.11| 400   | 500
```

this is what i have tried

```
 <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td *ngFor=" let key of accountList">
            {{key.AccountName}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor=" let res of accountList">
          {{res.Amount}}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

this generates 3 hortizontal rows, i want all in one line for the corresponding heading.

Comment: JSON is a string format and the `JSON` tag should only be used when asking questions dealing with JSON *string* representation of JavaScript objects (and not just JavaScript objects themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd row is generating more rows (looping on the `tr`), not columns. Add another `td` level and loop on that:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor=" let key of accountList">
        {{key.AccountName}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor=" let res of accountList">
        {{res.Amount}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/MldBaGTVGEPi7apIT0V0?p=preview

Comment: this  generates all in one row

Comment: @faceturn Updated with a plunker - the code looks like it's working fine to me

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>  <td *ngFor=" let res of accountList"> {{res.Amount}} </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
<table>
  <td *ngFor=" let key of accountList">
    <tr>
      <th> {{ key.AccountName }} </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> {{ key.Amount }} </td>
   </tr>
  </td>
</table>
```

if you prefer only one `ngFor` in your template. (confirmed it working locally). This logic basically appends more and more columns (with header and value within, in 2 rows) to the right based on the array length. Hope it helps.